# Как с помощью компилятора gcc.exe создать .bin программу?

Tags: c

Под .bin программой подразумевается программа, которая срдержит в себе бинарный код, исполняемый непосредственно компьютером(Без ОС)

Comment: Эм.. Это либо вопрос "как создать ОС", либо его надо переформулировать. И скорее второе, чем первое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
$ cc -c test.c
$ objcopy -O binary test.o binfile
```